# Is it good practice for Java class names to be plural?

Tags: java, class, naming-conventions

Is it good to have Java class name like `ExtractionUtils`? In naming conventions I couldn't find anything about using plural names for Java classes.
I have seen classes with names like this before.

Comment: I think most would say it is perfectly fine to have a plural class name.

Comment: I have a query regarding the naming convention , i want to create a been  which will store list of repair job of a product. Then which name will be appropriate like:- ProductJob or ProductJobs, Please suggest.

Comment: Package names equivalent: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/75919/78534

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), [`Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html), [`Utilities` [!]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html) - examples from JDK. It *kind of* violates OO design since all these classes are just namespaces holding utility or factory methods of objects in question while the name suggest they actually contain or maintain a collection of such objects. But being reasonable - I find these names readable and completely fine.

BTW looks like such a naming convention was very popular among Java 7 API designers.

Answer (score 6):

Yes perfectly acceptable to have plurals, look at `Collections` for example, it is a class which has many static methods which help when dealing with different flavours of collection.

Answer (score 6):

Only issue I see is that a "utils" is pretty ill-defined.  You want the class to refer to the object, not the collection of methods in the object.  Basically, it's just not a very object oriented name, and it's not even about OOP - a "utils" file is pretty poor structured programming often.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jls7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf . I found anything wrong about naming classes in plural.

Comment: The question is not whether it is valid in java but whether it is a standard practice.

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggetions.So the conclusion is plurals are allowed in class name but it should be named properly.